# How can I revise this pl/pgsql functions?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have a PostgreSQL extension function which could first check if there is a row in table face_area(face int, area float), if there is none, calculate and insert into the table. The returning should be area (float), the input should be face (int). I wrote a function below, but the result can only be setof float, how can I revise the function to let the returning result is just a single float?

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_area (face integer) RETURNS setof float AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN query  SELECT area  FROM face_area WHERE face_area.face=$1;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO face_area VALUES ($1,calc_area($1));
END IF;           
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select get_area(1);
select * from face_area;
```

Comment: Can you clarify the WHERE clause?  you describe face_area as (id int, area float) but use a column "face"...?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe I have revised it.

Comment: Also, why SETOF float?  Why do you need to return a query result?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe I need to return area=get_area(face) so that in another query I can use WHERE get_area(face)>5; so, I do not want setof float , I want just float. But I don't know how to revise the query...

Comment: This can be done with a single statement: `insert into face_area (face, area) select 42, calc_area(42) where not exists (select 1 from face_area where face = 42) returning face_area.area`. You also shouldn't use `float`: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_area (face integer) RETURNS  float AS $$
DECLARE
        RSLT float;
BEGIN
SELECT area into rslt FROM face_area WHERE face_area.face=$1;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    rslt := calc_area ($1);
    INSERT INTO face_area VALUES ($1,rslt);
END IF;   
return rslt;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You need to have a RETURN statement.  I added in the RSLT variable to hold the calculated area value and also to return it.